# osgeo has an import error libspatialite

Tags: python, anaconda, gdal

I have been using `osgeo` to deal with geotiffs. I was trying to change projections for one of my geotiffs, and I wasn't getting a correct return from

```
proj.ImportFromEPSG(3857)
```

This was because I installed `osgeo` with anaconda, and it did not come with the GDAL_DATA. I had GDAL installed on my unix system anyway, so I found the GDAL_DATA and created an environmental variable.

Somehow, in doing all of this, I have broken `osgeo`. I now get:

```
ImportError: /usr/lib/libspatialite.so.7: undefined symbol: GEOSDelaunayTriangulation_r
```

I have libspatialite installed, and I haven't really found anyone else having this issue. I have uninstalled and reinstalled `gdal` (i.e. `osgeo`) through anaconda a few times without success. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to fix the `ImportError` issue,

```
conda install --yes -c https://conda.binstar.org/jgomezdans gdal=1.11.0
```

Comment: Could you elaborate what this does?  I am also having issue using libspatialite from gdal-python

Comment: I believe it installs a special gdal python that comes with a file that was not included in the standard download currently. This person fixed that and but it on conda.binstar so that it could be downloaded through conda

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me for this was the following:

- look in `/lib` for older versions of the libraries
- delete them
- try again.

I had a bunch of old 32-bit libraries (I've updated my system in place for years), and these were being found first.

```
sudo rm -rf /lib/libspatiali*
sudo rm -rf /lib/libgeos*
```

Most of these file were from 2016/17, and deleting them solved my problem.